# Clearing the form fields after submit in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

How to clear the for, fields once the data is submitted.After clicking on submit the data in the text box is not getting cleared.

HTML:

```
function html_form_code() {
echo '<div class="thb_subscribe">';
echo '<h3 class="subscriberlogin">SUBSCRIBE</h3>';
echo '<p class="subscribertext">Subscribe now to get notified about latest updates!!</p>';
echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';

echo '<div class="emails" style="margin-left: -308px;">';
echo '<input type="email" id="cf-email" name="cf-email" placeholder="Your E-Mail" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-email"] ) : '' ) . '" size="42" required />';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="subjectline" style="display:none;">';
echo 'Subject (required) <br/>';
echo '<input type="text" name="cf-subject" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" value=" Subscription List"  />';
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="signup"><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Sign Up"></div>';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';
 }
```

Script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#cf-email').val(''); //txtID is textbox ID
});​
```

Tried with this code but it is not working.

Sending Email:

```
function deliver_mail() {

// if the submit button is clicked, send the email
if ( isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {

    // sanitize form values
    $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["cf-email"] );
    $subject = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-subject"] );
    $message = "This person $email  has been subscribed to your channel. ";

    // get the blog administrator's email address       
    $to = 'XXXX@gmail.com';

    $headers = "From:  <$email>" . "\r\n";

    // If email has been process for sending, display a success message
    if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<div id="deletesuccess">Thanks for Subscribing .</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo 'An unexpected error occurred';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How does your form gets submitted, through AJAX?

Comment: Your selecting on the ID #cf-email your field does not have that id, only the name. set an id="cf-email "

Comment: Sorry.. my bad... it does. :)

Comment: @VA79 i have added id in the form field as well

Comment: @user8001297 Would you mind to answer the question of 31piy ? It is an important fact.

Comment: @31piy not using any AJAX and all once i click on submit calling the other function posted that function as well

Comment: Maybe this is an effect of an option in browsers that stores all entered form data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .reset() on your form.

```
$(".myform")[0].reset();
```

Comment: I dint mention any class with myform where we need to add this class in the form or else in submit button

Comment: give an class or an id to your <form> tag like this :                             
                                                                                                              echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post"  id="myform" >';                                                          
                                                                                                               
and then use                                                                         


$("#myform")[0].reset();

Comment: Not working added id="myform" in form and in js changed to #myform but not working

Comment: Please add class name or id for form

Comment: added in form as id="myform" and change in js file as well but not working

Comment: use # instead of dot

Comment: OR if you want to use javascript instead of jquery use this ::: 
                                                 
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();                                                                        
                                                                                                           
 Check this simple example : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_reset

Comment: Please try $("#myform")[0].reset(); or jQuery("#myform")[0].reset(); in your console

Comment: @Deepa tried in that format but once i click on signup tit is clearing the text field not getting any emails and thank you message as well

Comment: @user8001297 : are you sure you clearing after sending mail  ?

Comment: After clicking on signup form i am not getting any email it is clearing the field directly.

Comment: Before that i have checked i am getting emails

Answer (score 0):

Try below scenarios:

First: Use $_POST empty where you finish your process.

```
$_POST = array();
```

Second: Use below script:

```
 $("form").submit() {
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
 });
```

Third: After finish your process just referesh the page use PHP:

```
header("Location: http://example.com/");
```

Comment: Its not in in core php it is wordpress